# How to sync an excel pivot-table with a sharepoint list?

Tags: excel, synchronization

I have a sharepoint list that I would like to connect and sync with a pivot table included in an excel file.
The excel fiel is a 2010 version and is stored in the same sharepoint.
Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.
Joel

Answer (score 0):

you have two approaches

1.- install the powerpivot add-in for sharepoint, this will allow you to export lists as data feeds that can be loaded and refreshed from excel

2.- if you have excel 2016 you can import data from excel from the data tab/get and transform , new query from sharepoint, then on save and load you can load the result to a pivot table or a powerpivot data model